# Setting the value of FilteringSelect Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a FilteringSelect with a jsonRest and ObjectStore

```
var store = new JsonRest({
        target: "categories"
});

var select = new FilteringSelect({
        store: ObjectStore({objectStore: store}),
        searchAttr: "id",
        invalidMessage : "Error"
});
```

The problem is when I try to set the default value, it doesn't change and makes a request to the url with the value appended. For example, if I do this:

```
this.select .set("value", "Hello");
```

it doesn't appear nothing in the select and makes a request to "categories/Hello"

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `set('value', id)`, the `get(id, ?options)` method of the backing store is called to obtain the item so the widget has the label to display. You are using `dojo/store/JsonRest`, so the item ID is appended to the URL for the XHR call.

If you have the item you want to set then use `set('item', item)`.